# Updating a property of an object by search in c#

Tags: c#

I have a data structure as follows: I have a list of objects with properties that i want to search for and then when i have found all the objects matching my search query, i want to update another property for all the found objects. Here is an example of the object's properties:

```
Name: Sean Aston
City: Toronto
Eye Color: Blue
Warnings: 4

Name: Cole Anderson
City: New York City
Eye Color: Black
Warnings: 1

Name: Polly Smith
City: Toronto
Eye Color: Blue
Warnings: 3
```

My search woluld be select all those objects in the list whose properties eye color is blue and city is toronto. It should return me objects one and three. Then i should be able to update the warnings property of the first and third object to increment by 1.

How can i achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361921/list-manipulation-in-c-using-linq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match your exact request would look like this:

```
foreach (var item in MyObjectList.Where(o => o.EyeColor == "Blue" && o.City == "Toronto"))
{
    item.Warnings ++;
}
```

But I suspect the criteria is entirely determined by the user, and so you don't know what you're looking for at compile time like this.  In that case:

```
var search = (IEnumerable<MyObject>)MyObjectList;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCity.Text))
{
    search = search.Where(o => o.City == txtCity.Text);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEyeColor.Text))
{
    search = search.Where(o => o.EyeColor == txtEyeColor.Text);
}

// similar checks for name or warning level could go here

foreach(var item in search) {item.Warnings++;}
```

Comment: Arg... the last question I answered was in vb.net and so I had the vb equality operator in there for a while :(

Answer (score 4):

How about this

```
People.Where(p => p.EyeColor == "blue" && p.City == "Toronto")
      .ToList().ForEach(p => p.Warnings++);
```

Comment: +1 That's exactly what I was writing when your post was loaded! =)

Comment: I don't like the .ToList() call in there. It creates bad habits.  I know you need that for the ForEach extension, but is it that hard to put it in a foreach() loop?

Comment: I agree with Joel.  I know this is just an example though... but code readability is always paramount :)

Comment: @Zero - I was thinking more about performance. This code is readable-enough to me, but `.ToList()` is very bad for performance.  Using it here means he's looping over the resulting objects twice, and holding an extra set of references in memory. It's even worse in other scenarios. For 4 records of sample data, it doesn't matter. But the actual data set is almost certainly much larger.

Comment: Good points. I admit I have a tendency to overuse the ToList() just because I really like the ForEach syntax

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an `IEnumerable<YourType>` (array, List, etc.), you will do this:

```
var filtered = yourlist.Where(o => o.EyeColor == "Blue" && o.City =="Toronto")
foreach(item in filtered)
{
    item.Warnings++;
}
```