# Search in List with C# and edit its value

Tags: c#-4.0

How Search in List with C# and edit its value
 find is there 5, change its value with 9?

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>() { 8, 5, 6, 2, 3 };
```

Comment: Use `foreach` / `for` / `lamda` / `myList[i]` google?

Comment: If you don't need to preserve the order of your lists items, you can use `RemoveAll`, and add that number of elements back to your list. RemoveAll returns the number of elements removed, so that's how to know how many to add back.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361921/list-manipulation-in-c-sharp-using-linq spelt lambda wrong in my first comment...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the situation, you could do something like this

```
myList = myList.Select(e => e.Equals(5) ? 9 : e).ToList<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I could not think of anything better than:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>{ 8, 5, 6, 2, 3 };
while (myList.IndexOf(5)!=-1)
{
    myList[myList.IndexOf(5)] = 9;
}
```

You could wrap it in an Extension method and use it like this:

```
myList.Replace(5, 9);

public static class ListExt
{
    public static void Replace<T>(this List<T> list, T old, T @new)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < list.Count; index++)
        {
            if(Equals(list[index], old))
                list[index] = @new;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a simple for loop and check whether the value of the current element equals 5 and if so just set it to 9, like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<myList.Count(); i++)
{
    if(myList[i]==5)
    {
         myList[i]=9;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Find the "5" element, and change it :
short d = 0;
while ((TheList[d] != 5) && ( d < TheList.Count()))
{
   d++;
}
if (d < TheList.Count())
TheList[d] = 9;
```

Comment: I do not recommend using this just because it feels very cryptic, no offense but I don't see why you didn't use a `for` loop?